# Getting Undefined property: stdClass::$options when using a foreach on an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, foreach

I have an PHP object - $new_step.

In Laravel, if I dd on a child object that is an array - `dd($new_step->data->options);` - of it, I get a valid entry:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => {#695 ▼
    +"position": 1
    +"value": "Dogs"
  }
  1 => {#694 ▼
    +"position": 2
    +"value": "Cats"
  }
  2 => {#693 ▼
    +"position": 3
    +"value": "Ferretts"
  }
  3 => {#669 ▼
    +"position": 4
    +"value": "Gophers"
  }
  4 => {#665 ▼
    +"position": 5
    +"value": "Possum"
  }
]
```

However, when I try to do a foreach on the object:

```
        foreach ($new_step->data->options as $options) {
            $options->count = 0;
        }
```

I get this error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined property: stdClass::$options
```

Why does the foreach fail?

Comment: isn't what you have there is an array?

Comment: It is, I clarified that the array is a child of the object.

Comment: You have to loop `$new_step->data->options[0]`? Since, it's objects inside array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that there was an array in the iteration that was an object and not an array. To test, I moved the `for` loop further out of the chain and tested each iteration thru it to see that the 5th iteration was the one responsible for causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

To do that `foreach` you must store a result of Object in the variable.

```
$temp = $new_step->data->options;
foreach ($temp as $options) {
    $options->count = 0;
}
```

At the end, you will get in your list `count` variable for each array as you want?

Do `dd($temp)` below `foreach` to check result.
If you again don't get right array probably you have some bug in `$new_step->data->options`.